# How to split images using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, split

I have an image which contains multiple images in it. I want to split the image into multiple image files, one file per image. How do I do this using ImageMagick?

I have attached a sample image file.

[image: Image file with multiple image within it]

Comment: `convert -crop geometry`

Answer (score 8):

To simply split your image into quadrants (same size) use [`crop+repage`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile):

```
convert image.jpg -crop 50%x50% +repage piece_%d.jpg
```

If you need different size quadrants you could [cut around a single point](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_quad):

```
convert image.jpg -crop 240x280+0+0 +repage piece_1.jpg
convert image.jpg -crop 0x280+240+0 +repage piece_2.jpg
convert image.jpg -crop 240x0+0+280 +repage piece_3.jpg
convert image.jpg -crop +240+280 +repage piece_4.jpg
```

[image]